# JWT vs custom encryption for REST APIs over https

Tags: rest, jwt

For our REST API architecture, we are currently thinking over two options -

1. Json Web Token - pros are that it is industry standard, we pass a key which adds a layer of access control and using which we can also add secondary authorisation restrictions at our backend, maintenance of session and related security features are provided by Django by default.

Cons are that the params are open for anyone to see, it seems (and correct me if I'm mistaken) that it is possible that if someone gets access to our link, he could alter a param that is not linked with the core authentication process and thus compromise the data.

2. An in house encryption process we developed that encrypts all the params. Pros are that we are fairly certain of it to have never been compromised, for even if the link would have gotten into the hands of someone they wouldn't have known how to decrypt it to look at the params.

Cons are that we have to manage all the session data through our backend code in our tables, so we aren't able to utilize the Django features. also, the idea that what we are doing isn't industry standard.

What is the right way to decide in this situation, and what are the factors that we should take into account?

Comment: It might be a better forum to discuss on Information Security https://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: "An in house encryption process we developed that encrypts all the params. Pros are that we are fairly certain of it to have never been compromised..." **No. No no no no no.** https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

Answer (score 1):

I am quoting from your question here:

> Cons are that the params are open for anyone to see, it seems (and >correct me if I'm mistaken) that it is possible that if someone gets >access to our link, he could alter a param that is not linked with the >core authentication process and thus compromise the data.

I think there is some misconception here about the JWT payload (or params as you call it). It is true that the payload is only Base64 encoded, and anyone who has access to the token can decode the payload and retrieve the information. However, they cannot **change** the payload, since the signature will invalidate it on the server side. This should ideally result in blacklisting of the JWT token. What you should be careful about is that no sensitive information (password, DOB etc.) should be included in the payload.

> An in house encryption process we developed that encrypts all the params. >Pros are that we are fairly certain of it to have never been compromised, >for even if the link would have gotten into the hands of someone they >wouldn't have known how to decrypt it to look at the params.

Closing off the encryption algorithm cannot guarantee security. Such systems are also very difficult to scale, and vulnerable to version errors. Programmers can bring the entire authentication system down because the algorithm was not documented correctly. Worse, they would be afraid to ever touch it again and not fix things wrong with it or try to improve it across versions. This becomes a technical debt which is very hard to pay off.

**JWT**

If you do decide to use JWT in your architecture, use the refresh tokens for long lived sessions and keep the JWT token expiry short. On the client side, not storing the token in localStorage provides an additional layer of security. You can store the refresh token in a cookie, and use it when then token has expired.